# New Windows 10 PC Bluescreens when idle

Tags: windows, windows-10, bsod

I have a brand new build, Windows 10, Asus Z170-P motherboard, 12gb corsair ddr4, GTX 950, 1TB hard drive.  Whenever I leave it idle it seems to bluescreen.  This can happen after 20-30 minutes or not for an hour or more.  Usually when I'm using it actively playing games it is fine.  The bluescreen bug check string is various things from MEMORY_MANAGEMENT, IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL, BAD_POOL_HEADER and a few others.

The minidumps for all the recent bluescreens are here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-wOckrdsYnYWG5RYlVOMF9xaTg/view?usp=sharing

Things I've tried:

- Updating all my drivers, particularly the asus chipset drivers
- Running Memtest overnight (7 passes in 9 hours, no issues found)
- chkdisk (via windows 10 tools)

I really am stuck now.  I took it back to the store where I bought all the parts and they said they tested it and it's all fine (they updated the chipset drivers again even though I had already done so) and for them it was running for 2 hours with no bluescreen.

If anyone has suggestions I'd be really grateful because I've run out of ideas!

UPDATE

Memory timings from CPU-Z added below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Varying BSOD codes, especially when "Memory_Management" is involved, is almost always bad RAM, except when it's a faulty RAM controller on the board.  Test each stick of RAM individually for 72 hours (continuous) with Memtest, or if you bought them as a kit, try to get a replacement set and try those for a few days. Basically try/test it with each stick individually to try and find the culprit, the downside its that it may be a timing issue with (one of) the sticks, and it may only be a problem if you have more than one installed.  Welcome to building your own computer. :)

Comment: Bad RAM, ok thanks for the suggestion!  I have 3x4GB sticks in there so I can try one at a time on it's own and seeing what happens.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a memory corruption:

```
STACK_TEXT:  
00 nt!KeBugCheckEx
01 nt! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'
02 nt!MiDeleteVad
03 nt!MmCleanProcessAddressSpace
04 nt!PspRundownSingleProcess
05 nt!PspExitThread
06 nt!NtTerminateProcess
07 nt!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd
08 0x0

CHKIMG_EXTENSION: !chkimg -lo 50 -d !nt
    fffff800e278fd0d-fffff800e278fd0e  2 bytes - nt!MiPurgeZeroList+6d
    [ 80 fa:00 ee ]
2 errors : !nt (fffff800e278fd0d-fffff800e278fd0e)

MODULE_NAME: memory_corruption

IMAGE_NAME:  memory_corruption

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  memory_corruption

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  MEMORY_CORRUPTION_LARGE

BUCKET_ID:  MEMORY_CORRUPTION_LARGE

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  MEMORY_CORRUPTION_LARGE
```

I see you use an relatively old BIOS/UEFI:

```
BiosVersion = 0705
BiosReleaseDate = 02/23/2016
BaseBoardManufacturer = ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
BaseBoardProduct = Z170-P
```

[ASUS released several newer BIOS/UEFI](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/Z170-P/HelpDesk_Download/) versions. [Try the version 2003](http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/LGA1151/Z170-P/Z170-P-ASUS-2003.zip) from September 2016. Also look that the RAM timings are set correctly in the UEFI/BIOS.

Comment: Currently going through the suggestion above (rotating the RAM to see if things keep crashing) so I will update the BIOS once that is done.  Thank you so much for looking into the dump files! I'll come back and mark as accepted if this works

Comment: any update on the issue?

Comment: Yes! I updated the BIOS and now only have the 8gb pair (2x4gb) sticks of ram and not the other single one and I haven't seen a BSOD for 24+ hrs.  I still have to try putting the last piece of ram back in and see if it's the ram or the BIOS update. Will update this once I'm 100% sure.

Comment: 5 days running with no issues and it just bluescreened again!  I thought we had it fixed but I guess not.  It seems to be the same memory_management error too.  Same thing though, I have 8gb matched pair with the new BIOS.  Would you suggest trying completely new RAM?

Comment: run CPU-Z and look in the memory/SPD tab if the RAM timings match: http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html

Comment: Comparing the values in the Memory tab to the SPD tab the values for each of the timings are similar/close but not matching.  For example on Memory the tRAS says 36 clocks but on SPD it ranges from 35 to 39.  I'm not sure which values are essential to have matching?  I run the validator it created this link: http://valid.x86.fr/njw3pf

Comment: I can't open the link. add pictures to your question

Comment: I've added the timings to the question. Thanks for looking at this!

Comment: 1200MHz is the XMP profile wich is not stable all the time. switch to 1066/2133MHz. Also Corsair RAM and ASUS boards is often causing such stability issues.

Comment: is the PC now stable with reduced memory frequency?

Comment: Well, I changed it to 2133Mhz and it crashed maybe 10 minutes later.  At 2400MHz it was a lot more stable although it did crash every few hours, especially more if I am not doing anything on the computer.  Not sure what else to try to be honest

Comment: do you have a friend with a relatively new PC who also uses DDR4 RAM? If yes, try his RAM and put your RAM into his PC and look what happens. Corsair RAM and ASUS Boards is a bad combination. I saw such strange issues very often with this combination

Comment: Ok I can take the RAM back to the shop and try a different brand, thanks for the suggestions

Comment: ok, try a Kingston or Crucial 2133 RAM like the Crucial DIMM Kit 8GB, DDR4-2133, CL15 (CT2K4G4DFS8213). In German price search sites it ha a good reputation and it is cheap. Also look in the manual which RAM is supported and tested

Comment: does new RAM fix the issue?

Comment: Hi, no it didn't fix the issue and I ended up returning the PC to the store.  They reformatted and reinstalled windows and claimed they had no crashes so the assumption was it was an issue with drivers.

Comment: For future readers of this question, the issue was most likely a drivers issue according to the test engineers either the motherboard drivers or graphics card drivers but there was no confirmation as the PC was reset to factory settings.  I'm marking this answer as accepted because of all the help @magicandre1981 gave me but it's not exactly the correct answer.